# How did a <3k user vote to close a question?

Tags: support, reputation, vote-to-close

From [this LQP review item](https://askubuntu.com/review/low-quality-posts/219372):

> [image]

but the user 'Olli' has only 2,804 rep (at time of writing), how did he 'Close' it?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It was a flag (not a close vote).

Avinash Raj submitted the first flag and Olli confirmed it.

Comment: Do you have the users the wrong way around?

Comment: I might. I honestly might. My original draft was the other way around but the timeline is so screwy (it's in two parts on two pages) that I wasn't ever quite sure. Either way, I'm *fairly* sure both the original votes were flags. I think.